# Embedding Unique IDs before LSTM layer

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to predict the value of one feature for 39 unique IDs. 117 is `3*39` where 3 are the timesteps and each timestep has values for 39 different IDs (numeric). I am trying to solve this by using an Embedding layer before LSTM layer, and because I want to predict value of a feature for all unique IDs using a single model, but I am getting error when trying to fit the model. Please correct where I'm wrong.
Would it make more sense if instead the shape of data is (360,3,39,8). I tried this approach but LSTM needs input in the shape of (num_sequences,timesteps,features), and (360,3,39,8) adds 1 more dimension and i get the error of shape mismatch for LSTM input.
Shape of all data as below:

```
X_train_sequences = (360,117,8)  
Y_train_sequences = (390,39,1) #(because lead time = 1)  
X_train_arpt = (360,117,1)
```

```
feature_inp shape: (None, 117, 8)
arpt_inp shape: (None, 39)
arpt_emb shape: (None, 39, 9)
arpt_emb_repeated shape: (None, 3, 39, 9) 
arpt_emb_rehaped shape (None, 117, 9)
concatenated_inp shape: (None, 117, 17)
(None, 64)
(None, 39)
```

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-852b26bbd87b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit([X_train_sequences, X_train_arpt], Y_train_sequences, batch_size = 16, epochs = 20)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 1 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 39), found shape=(None, 117, 1)
```

```
emb_size = 9
# Input layers
feature_inp = Input(shape = (num_timesteps*n_arpts, n_features))
print("feature_inp shape:", feature_inp.shape)
arpt_inp = Input(shape = (n_arpts,))
print("arpt_inp shape:", arpt_inp.shape)

# Embedding layer
arpt_emb = Embedding(n_arpts, emb_size)(arpt_inp)
print("arpt_emb shape:", arpt_emb.shape)

# Repeat embedding layer to match with num_timesteps * n_arpts
arpt_emb_repeated = repeat(expand_dims(arpt_emb, axis = 1), repeats=num_timesteps, axis=1)
print("arpt_emb_repeated shape:", arpt_emb_repeated.shape)

# Reshape to match input features
arpt_emb_rehaped = Reshape((-1, emb_size))(arpt_emb_repeated)
print("arpt_emb_rehaped shape",arpt_emb_rehaped.shape)

# Concatenate features and embeddign layer
concatenated_inp = Concatenate(axis = -1)([feature_inp, arpt_emb_rehaped])
print("concatenated_inp shape:", concatenated_inp.shape)

lstm_1 = LSTM(64)(concatenated_inp)
print(lstm_1.shape)

out = Dense(39, activation = 'linear')(lstm_1)
print(out.shape)

model = Model(inputs= [feature_inp, arpt_inp], outputs = out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
model.fit([X_train_sequences, X_train_arpt], Y_train_sequences, batch_size = 16, epochs = 20)
```

Comment: I have edited to include the traceback.

Comment: The error report indicates you have an incorrect shape, We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: @itprorh66 kindly stop repeating that "*We don't provide debugging services*" to a new user. While it is true that we don't provide *any* kind of service, debugging *help* and *assistance* is exactly what we provide as a community (and I don't mean merely providing possibly helpful general links).

Comment: I actually posted this hoping that someone could may be check and guide me with my logic.

Comment: @desertnaut, if we do supply debugging services than why does [What topics can I ask about here?]{https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic} warn some questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") questions maybe closed by the community because they fail to include information related to the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and don't include the shortest code necessary to reproduce problem.  I believe this question fits into that category, since OP doesn't seem to know what the right answer is.

Comment: @itprorh66 the question *used* to lack this necessary info indeed, and it was later edited to include it. Still, this is a totally different issue - you could/should vote to close the question with the appropriate reason. Claiming instead that "*We don't provide debugging services*" sends a completely different message (which the on-topic page, explaining how to get *debugging help* here, does not corroborate).